# How to access to the post build artifact in pre-send script for editable email notification?

Tags: jenkins, email-ext, jenkins-email-ext

I'm trying to access an archived post build artifact, extract, reformat the data and send it out in an editable email notification.

However, I'm struggling to find a way to access the artifact in the pre-send script.

Any suggestions on what I can do?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using freestyle projects, you can set a file as the mail's content in your presend script:

```
def reportPath = build.getWorkspace().child("mail.txt"); 
msg.setContent(reportPath.readToString(), "text/plain");
```

In declarative pipelines:

```
emailext (
    body: readFile('mail.txt')
)
```

You can add anything to that .txt file; for example, I include the changed file names to the mail (using SVN), and the error log:

```
echo Build successful, changeset: > mail.txt && svn diff -r COMMMITTED:PREV >> mail.txt

echo Build failed, changeset: > mail.txt && svn diff -r COMMMITTED:PREV >> mail.txt && echo Errors: >> mail.txt && cat error.log >> mail.txt
```